# Thymeleaf: Can I use messages inside expressions

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, el

I am using Thymeleaf 3 within a Spring Boot application.
Currently I am in a situation where I want to use a message expression inside an EL expression (Spring EL).

First use case: trim the message

```
data:title="${#{message.key}.trim()}
```

Second use case: conditionally create an attribute with a message as its value

```
data:title="${condition ? #{message.key} : ''}
```

Both examples will produce a syntax error, because `#{` is not an allowed start of an expression.

Any ideas how to achieve what I want?

Comment: Checkout the following tutorial:  http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#a-multi-language-welcome

Comment: @karen I did. Unfortunately chapter "4.1 Messages" doesn't say anything about this. :( Apparently I had to read the entire tutorial ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[In both cases you'll want to use the `#messages` utility object.](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#messages-1)

```
data:title="${#messages.msg('key').trim()}"

data:title="${condition ? #messages.msg('key') : ''}"
```

Comment: Ah, I missed that. I already was on the verge to create my own Spring bean that would exactly do what `#messages` is doing. Thanks a lot!