# spring thymeleaf: use message key in message value

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Can I use a message key in a message value?
I am looking for something like:

messages.properties-file:

```
mykey.intro =Thanks for visiting the #{mykey.companyname} website.<br/>
mykey.main =At #{mykey.companyname} we like to foobar.<br/>
mykey.more =There is more at #{mykey.companyname}. Please see ....<br/>
mykey.companyname =<span class="myclass">FOObar</span>
```

The goal is to have a styled companyname added to the website at several places in the website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference another property in java.util.Properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872272/how-to-reference-another-property-in-java-util-properties)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412132/can-i-reference-another-property-in-a-properties-file-use-property

Comment: Anyone, has the answer for this? I don't think so it is duplicate. Becuase @trompetix want to achieve this in Thymleaf Spring.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231060/thymeleaf-can-i-use-messages-inside-expressions